# Sparse Cross Entropy Loss for calculating Loss in NLP problems. PyTorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

My Input tensor Looks like :

```
torch.Size([8, 23])

// where,
// 8 -> batch size
// 23 -> words in each of them
```

My output tensor Looks like :

```
torch.Size([8, 23, 103])

// where,
// 8 -> batch size
// 23 -> words predictions
// 103 -> vocab size.
```

I want to calculate sparse cross Entropy Loss for this task, but I can’t since PyTorch only calculates the loss single element. How can I code it to work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect as the outcome? Are you potentially looking for [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html)?

Comment: I am training an Encoder-Decoder network so each position in the output has 103(vocab size) positions to select from. But since in Pytorch I can only calculate the loss for one word, how am I supposed to calculate the total loss. I am using a transformer network.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, I am assuming you are coming from tensorflow, where `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` indeed works on tensors with shapes, you provided.

It is late, but in case someone stumbles upon this post;
it now also has an answer here: [torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss over Multiple Batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483124/torch-nn-crossentropyloss-over-multiple-batches)

As for torch, according to the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

`CrossEntropyLoss` assumes the second dimension to be of size of your classes, so you would only need to transpose the last two dimensions of your tensor like so:

```py
loss_obj = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

logits = model(model_input)  # shape(logits) -> (batch_size, seq_len, n_classes)
loss = loss_obj(torch.transpose(logits, -2, -1), y_true)  # shape(y_true) -> (batch_size, seq_len)
```